# Proc sql: Creating a view by copying data from one year to another

Tags: view, sas, subquery, left-join, proc-sql

I have a problem that I was not able to find a solution for on Stackoverflow or elsewhere and I am not sure, if it is possible do solve with SAS proc sql.

My aim is to produce a view (z) based on a dataset (a) and a view (b). The problem ist that (a) can be updated to the actual year at the beginning of the year, while (b) can only be updated later in the year. Nevertheless I want my view (z) to produce data at the beginning of the year (even if it is provisionally), what is naturally only possible if there is data available from both the (a) and (b). So what I want is that view (z) uses the latest available year from (b) and use it as if it would be the actual year (so basically to impute data into (b) for the latest data year in (a). I tried to do this with the following code, but it did not work exactly the way I want it:

```
proc sql;
create view x1 as 
   select ste.jahr, ste.gnr, ste.einwg, stk.stkabs
      from           d18.fg_gji_steinh as ste
                           inner join 
                        d18.fg_gji_skraft as stk
                                    on 
                        case when exists (select stkabs from d18.fg_gji_skraft where ste.jahr=stk.jahr)
                        then ste.jahr=stk.jahr and ste.gnr=stk.gnr
                        else input(ste.jahr,4.)=input(stk.jahr,4.)+1 and ste.gnr=stk.gnr
                        end 
                        order by ste.jahr, ste.gnr ;   
quit;
```

It produces the expected data in the first and the last year, but not in the years between as it produces there two rows for one observation. The first observation contains data from the actual year, the other observation contains data from the last year.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you want to do two joins.  One to find the actual (end of year) results and a second to find the predicted (beginning of year) results. Then in the select use COALESCE() function to prioritize returning the actual results when they are available.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected result to the question ?  I would guess you want to join to a correlated subquery of `fg_gji_skraft `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to just join twice. One where YEAR matches and one where YEAR+1 matches.  Then use COALESCE() function to pick which value to report. So something like

```
select a.jahr
     , a.gnr
     , a.einwg
     , coalesce(b.stkabs,c.stkabs) as stkabs
from d18.fg_gji_steinh a
left join d18.fg_gji_skraft b
  on a.gnr=b.gnr and a.jahr=b.jahr
left join d18.fg_gji_skraft c
  on a.gnr=c.gnr and a.jahr=(c.jahr + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed join (see answer below of Tom, Feb 6) works fine if the key variable values (jahr, gnr) are the same for the different years.
However, there is an additional problem that several municipalities can merge into a single municipality at begin of the year. This is expressed in the change of the community number (gnr). 
Both communities that merge get the same number, i.e. the number of the larger community or even a new number.
The values of the last known data (stkabs) must be copied to the following year, overwriting the missing data. 
If two communities merge, the data must be added.
Is this possible express in a view?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, using some subqueries. Maybe there is a simpler way to do it?

I modelled the different territorial levels with a format. 
It takes the territorial year and the municipality number 
as argument, and delivers the resulting municipality number of the new territorial level.

```
/* 
   Input data to view: tables fg_gji_steinh and fg_gji_skraft, 
   the tax units and defintive tax force, respectively.
   Data in fg_gji_skraft is missing in the last two years. This has to be filled
   by the view with the last known data, in this example from year 2019.
   Table fg_gji_steinh has to be joined with table fg_gji_skraft.
*/

data work.fg_gji_steinh;
   jahr='2018'; gnr='1001'; einwg=1.5; output;
   jahr='2018'; gnr='1002'; einwg=1.8; output;
   jahr='2018'; gnr='1003'; einwg=2.0; output;

   jahr='2019'; gnr='1001'; einwg=1.6; output;
   jahr='2019'; gnr='1002'; einwg=1.8; output;
   jahr='2019'; gnr='1003'; einwg=2.0; output;

   jahr='2020'; gnr='1002'; einwg=1.8; output;
   jahr='2020'; gnr='1010'; einwg=1.9; output;

   jahr='2021'; gnr='1010'; einwg=2.1; output;
run;

data work.fg_gji_skraft;
   jahr='2018'; gnr='1001'; stkabs=10; output;
   jahr='2018'; gnr='1002'; stkabs=20; output;
   jahr='2018'; gnr='1003'; stkabs=30; output;

   jahr='2019'; gnr='1001'; stkabs=10; output;
   jahr='2019'; gnr='1002'; stkabs=22; output;
   jahr='2019'; gnr='1003'; stkabs=35; output;

   jahr='2020'; gnr='1002'; stkabs=.; output;
   jahr='2020'; gnr='1010'; stkabs=.; output;

   jahr='2021'; gnr='1010'; stkabs=.; output;
run;

/*
   Municipal merger format. 
   We assume that in 2018 there exist three municipalities: 1001, 1002, 1003.
   The same in 2019.
   At begin of year 2020 municipalities 1001 and 1003 merge to 1010.
   At begin of year 2021 municipalities 1002 and 1010 merge to 1010.
*/
proc format;
   value $cjrgdgdf
   '20201001'='1010'
   '20201002'='1002'
   '20201003'='1010'
   '20201010'='1010'
   '20211001'='1010'
   '20211002'='1010'
   '20211003'='1010'
   '20211010'='1010'
   ;
run;

/* definitive tax force */
%macro select1;
   select
      jahr,
      gnr,
      stkabs
   from fg_gji_skraft
%mend select1;

/* join tax units and definitive tax force */
%macro select2;
   select
      t1.*,
      t2.stkabs
   from
      fg_gji_steinh as t1
   left join
      ( %select1 ) as t2
   on t1.jahr=t2.jahr and t1.gnr=t2.gnr
%mend select2;

/* last data year of definitive tax force*/
%macro select3;
   select max (jahr) as maxjahr
   from ( %select1 )
   where stkabs ne .
%mend select3;

/* last known definitive tax force */
%macro select4;
   select
      t1.jahr,
      t1.gnr,
      t1.stkabs
   from ( %select2 ) as t1
   where t1.jahr=( %select3 )
%mend select4;

/* convert last known tax force to territorial level of first missing data year. */
%macro select5a;
   select
      put(input(jahr,4.)+1,4.) as jahr,
      put(calculated jahr||gnr,$cjrgdgdf.) as gnr,
      sum(stkabs) as stkabs
   from ( %select4 )
   group by jahr, calculated gnr
%mend select5a;

/* convert last known tax force to territorial level of second missing data year. */
%macro select5b;
   select
      put(input(jahr,4.)+2,4.) as jahr,
      put(calculated jahr||gnr,$cjrgdgdf.) as gnr,
      sum(stkabs) as stkabs
   from ( %select4 )
   group by jahr, calculated gnr
%mend select5b;

/* join definitive tax force with provisional tax force. */
%macro select6;
   select
      t1.jahr,
      t1.gnr,
      coalesce(t1.stkabs, t2.stkabs, t3.stkabs) as stkabs
   from
      (%select2 ) as t1
   left join
      ( %select5a ) as t2
   on t1.jahr=t2.jahr AND t1.gnr=t2.gnr
   left join
      ( %select5b ) as t3
   on t1.jahr=t3.jahr AND t1.gnr=t3.gnr
%mend select6;

/* finally join tax units with tax force */
proc sql;
   create view
       fg_gji_steuerfuss_gb AS
   select
      t1.jahr,
      t1.gnr,
      t1.einwg,
      t2.stkabs
   from
      fg_gji_steinh as t1,
      ( %select6 ) as t2
   where
      t1.jahr=t2.jahr and t1.gnr=t2.gnr
   ;
quit;
```